# Call to REST API gives Internal Server Error, How to Debug?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, model-view-controller, wildfly, ehcache-3

I have Spring MVC application, which I have build. The output or artifact is WAR file. The WAR file is deployed successfully in the WildFly. But when I make call to API, it throws the Internal Server Error.
Below the changes which I made, Before this changes API calls were working fine.

mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
xmlns:cache="http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache/spring-cache.xsd ">

<cache:annotation-driven cache-manager="ehCacheManager"/>

<bean id="ehCacheManager" class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheCacheManager">
    <property name="cacheManager">
    <bean class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="configLocation" value="/WEB-INF/ehcache.xml" />
    </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

pom.xml

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.ehcache</groupId>
      <artifactId>ehcache</artifactId>
     <version>3.2.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
 </dependency>
```

What could be the error? How can I debug and see what is causing the error? I am unable to see any log files related to this.

Comment: without log/error details, finding  ***error*** here is kind of finding needle in haystack. try to regenerate the error so that others can help you better.

Comment: Can you tell where I can find the error? I checked in wildfly logs but couldn't find any.

Comment: for that particular api call, try to find the weakpoint and use `try-catch` to get the probable error with stacktrace. That may lead you to main problem

Comment: Ok i will try that, but this issue comes for all API calls. I think some issue with 'ehCacheManager' bean initialization may be.